# Posicionamiento CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Hola buenas noches tengo 4 tablas las cuales estan encerradas en un div y quiero poner la segunda columna en el area dibujada , de ante mano muchas gracias]

Hola buenas noches tengo 4 tablas las cuales estan encerradas en un div y quiero poner la segunda columna en el area dibujada , de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour]. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué llevas de código? Danos más datos para poder orientarte :)

Comment: Puedes ponernos el código con lo que has hecho?

Answer (score 2):

creo que con esto bastaría, imagina este caso:

```css
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper .caja:first-child {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.caja {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50ppx;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <a class="caja">Caja Izquierda</a>
  <a class="caja">Caja derecha</a>
 </div>
```